# How can I ignore or drop title and footnotes in Pandas Frames that reads an Excel file?

Tags: pandas

I read a xls file to a pandas frame, and I need to remove the title and footnotes and keep the columns data

Comment: Have you seen the docs? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html  You will read about the `skiprows=`, `nrows=`, and `usecols=` parameters, they should help you with your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.